# How do you contain and position an input with a div?

Tags: html, css

How do you manage to get an input box positioned perfectly inside a div?

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="field">
    <input type="text" id="field1">

    </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#field1 {
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
}
.field {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 160px;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mtuj99n2/2/

Comment: As this updated fiddle shows, the input nests nicely in the div. Please clarify your question. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/mtuj99n2/4

Comment: Just reduce the width of input by 1%.

Comment: Move the border to the input and remove it from the div.

Comment: set padding: 0 0 0 0;

Comment: If you are talking about the border not appearing properly on the right, set padding to 0 for the input

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/mtuj99n2/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got so many different properties at your disposal in css that you could use to do this. I just have a sample here:

```
#inputField {

width: 90%;
height: 100%;
border: 1px solid red;
margin-left: 5px;
margin-top:5px;
}
```